# UICollectionViewCell goes over sticky header

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've a strange behavior with `UICollectionView`.

In Figure 1 is shown the correct behavior when the user scroll up the collection: the items goes under header view.

[image]
[FIGURE 1]

When I reload Items after a search, some items goes over header during scroll.

[image]

I've no idea about the cause...
Any ideas or suggestions?
Thanks.

*EDIT*

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds), CGRectGetWidth([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds) * 0.612f);
}
```

Comment: Are you using UIViewController or UICollectionViewController?

Comment: Can you tell me where is your top constrain of UICollectionView? Is that on UIView top layout or Searchbar bottom?

Comment: @AbilashBNair UIViewController with a UICollectionView added on it

Comment: @AbilashBNair search bar is in the header; is not an extern element added to the view controller

Comment: Are you setting height for header?

Comment: @AbilashBNair yes, I set a CGSize

Comment: Can you share you code which you wrote on CollectionView Header delegate and CGSize?

Comment: @AbilashBNair I've edited the question

Comment: Can you do one check? Instead of calculation height during returning. Calculate before and pass the height variable during returning.

Comment: @AbilashBNair no difference...

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is to call `reloadData()` instead of trying to reload with animation (`reloadSections()`).

---

In my case, I had a show/hide button to toggle the number of rows in section between item count and 0 (expand the content of the section).

When I replaced

```
collectionView?.reloadSections([section])
```

with

```
collectionView?.reloadData()
```

I no longer had the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set **sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true** property on your **UICollectionViewFlowLayout**. Because every **UICollectionView** has own layout.

[Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout/1617699-sectionheaderspintovisiblebounds)

A Boolean value indicating whether headers pin to the top of the collection view bounds during scrolling.

Maybe it will help. Add this code into **viewDidLoad.**

```
(self.yourCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code, in order for it to be more useful.

Comment: I've added some description. :)

Answer (score 0):

My working code for UICollectionView along with HeaderView inside UIViewController:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 20;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(100, 100);
}


- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionReusableView *view = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"header" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return view;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     return CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 100);
}
```

**Storyboard:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Please check this. Hope this will help you in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many solutions in my case that works,

```
collectionView.clipsToBounds = true
```